# Laravel grab related models based on tags

Tags: laravel, relation

I have two models, `Expense` and `Tag`, which have a Many to Many relation.

For each Expense, I can add multiple tags, which are stored in a pivot table using `sync`. The table is called `expense_tag`.

Now on my `expenses.show` page, I want to display details about one expense, obviously. But, I want to show ALL related expenses, using the tags relationship.

**The problem:**

I only have the information for one expense. Which means, I need to collect all tags that are assigned to that expense, and then using those tags, grab all expenses that were assigned one or more of those tags as well.

I want to refrain from having to use foreach loops to accomplish this. I've been trying with filter but I am unsure how to go about it. I just prefer keeping it simple.

Any suggestions for this?

My relations in my model:

Expense:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

Tag:

```
public function expenses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Expense::class);
}
```

Comment: Would a query built with the query builder be ok? I don't think i can do it with just eloquent

Comment: Yeah me neither, probably that's why I was asking here. But anything will do actually, since I haven't been able to figure it out yet, not even in a 'bad' way

Comment: i think i have a solution, will post answer after testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a `where in` clause

```
$tagIds = $expense->tags()->pluck('id')->toArray();
$expenseIds = DB::table('expense_tag')->
    whereIn('tag_id',$tagIds)->pluck('expense_id')->toArray();
$relatedexpenses = Expense::whereIn('id', $expenseIds)->get();
```

note: this uses 3 queries, so it might be slightly slower than a full sql solution, but it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks, tweaked it a little to exclude the current selected expense, and the queries is not an issue at the moment. it does the job for now, which is fine for me, thanks :)